# How to use dojox.form.Uploader (new html5 uploader) to upload multiple files to a server requiring OAuth?

Tags: html, file-upload, oauth, dojo

I'm trying to upload files to a server that requires OAuth signature of the POST url. I'm trying to do this with dojo html5 uploader widget that lets user select multiple files (dojox.form.Uploader).

As I understand, this widget seem to support only a single 'action' url. That means that all the files will be posted/uploaded to a single url (which I can intercept and sign before upload/submit). Is there a way to change the url of the individual file items before submitting ?

Regards,